# avoid .slice is not a function (javascript)

Tags: javascript

so i have a variable which as this point has a static definition, i want  it to get now the value dynamically from an `if-else` statement but the above mentioned error pops out:

```
var x = [{a:b},{c:d},{e:f}]
```

and i want to change it to get the value from a function:

```
var x = function(){
    if(true){
      return [{a:b},{c:d},{e:f}]
    }else{
      return [{f:g},{h:i}]
    }
}
```

But I get an error `x.slice is not a function`
Can what am i doing wrong? Looked around but cant manage to fix this... isn't it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

x is a function so it does not have slice you should run it before

```
var x = (function(){
    if(true){
      return [{a:b},{c:d},{e:f}]
    }else{
      return [{f:g},{h:i}]
    }
})()
```

Answer (score 4):

`x` is a function, so you're trying to call `.slice()` on a function. You want to call `x()` and use the return value, then slice that:

```
x().slice(1);
```

Comment: If he use your proposition then the function will be computed each time the needs the value. If it's time-consuming it can be problematic. Moreover if the condition change then x() will not return the same value at each call. I don't think it's what he want

Comment: @DARK_DUCK it depends on his use-case. Both answers cover the main reason why it's failing, mine is more geared towards a re-usable function, yours is demonstrating a one-time calculation. Neither is strictly wrong